# What bring assign to the 3 ways to forge synthetics cols in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With this sample data::

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 6, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 2},
                   'b': {0: 1, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1, 4: -1},
                   'c': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 4}})
```

I use one of this 3 forms to create a new column::

We do it with an **apply on axis=1**::

```
df['ts'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'XS' if x.a * x.b - x.c > 1 else 'L', axis=1)
```

Or with pandas **loc querying API** (used to be said slower)::

```
df.loc[:, 'ts2'] = 'L'
df.loc[df.a * df.b - df.c > 1, 'ts2'] = 'XL'
```

Or if else **np.where**::

```
df['ts3'] = np.where(df.a * df.b - df.c > 1, 'XS', 'L')
```

All three work well::

```
df
#    a  b  c  ts ts2 ts3
# 0  6  1  4  XS  XL  XS
# 1  4 -1  3   L   L   L
# 2  5  2  3  XS  XL  XS
# 3  4 -1  2   L   L   L
# 4  2 -1  4   L   L   L
```

Strangely the new pandas.v16 **assign** raise an error for this::

```
df.assign(ts4=lambda x: 'XS' if x.a * x.b - x.c > 1 else 'L')
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My feeling is that the assign method loses a lot of his interest if we can't use such constructions.

Comment: Well this works `df.assign(ts4=np.where(df.a * df.b - df.c > 1, 'XS', 'L'))`, the problem with expression `ts4=lambda x: 'XS' if x.a * x.b - x.c > 1 else 'L'` is that it wonly works in the apply because you're using `axis=1` so you're comparing single scalar values, your expression isn't so it's not valid

Comment: I don't see the interest of `assign` if we use `np.where` as I've show in my question we can create col with `df['ts3'] = np.where(df.a * df.b - df.c > 1, 'XS', 'L')`